How to find the previous day's date in YYYY-MM-DD format in Control M?
In the following two ways, I calculate, for example, some dates that I have as parameters in a control job m.
#Sysdate calculation - 1 (YYYYMMDD format for yesterday)
%%$CALCDATE %%$ODATE -1

#I calculate sysdate date (YYYY-MM-DD format for today) (The point is to concatenate)
%%$OYEAR.-%%OMONTH.-%%ODAY

My question is: how can I calculate yesterday's date in YYYY-MM-DD format?
That is, if today is June 18, 2024, how do I generate 2024-06-17?

Use the substring function - %%SUBSTR
PARM1=%%$CALCDATE %%$ODATE -1
PARM2=%%SUBSTR %%PARM1 1 4
PARM3=%%SUBSTR %%PARM1 5 2
PARM4=%%SUBSTR %%PARM1 7 2
PARM5=%%PARM2.-%%PARM3.-%%PARM4

echo %%PARM5

